# jQuery: разные функции для разной ширины экрана

Tags: jquery, html, css

Всем привет. У меня адаптивный сайт и там менюшка. На компе при наведении на пункт должно появляться подменю, а вот на смарте при нажатии меню должно выезжать. Все бы просто, но как сделать с этими телефонами.

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav').click(function(){
        console.log("Функция для телефона, планшета. Ширина 675px и меньше");
    });
    $('#nav').hover(function(){
        console.log("Функция для компьютера. Ширина экрана больше 675px");
    });

});
```

---

Вспомнив, как смартфоны обрабатывают Hover, я решил не заморачиваться по этому поводу и оставил как есть :) Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно проверять не на ширину, а на поддержу св-в. Touch событий, например.

```
var isTouch = document.ontouchstart ? true : false;
```

А дальше вешать событий в зависимости от поддержки. Хотя бы так:

```
if (isTouch) {
    $('#nav').click(function(){
            console.log("Функция для телефона, планшета.");
        });
} else {
     $('#nav').hover(function(){
            console.log("Функция для компьютера.");
        });        
}
```

Comment: Самый годный вариант, ведь на компе мы можем сделать маленькое окошечко, тогда это будет выглядеть не совсем хорошо.

Answer (score 2):

Самое правильное - это разделять приложение для пк и для мобильных устройств.

Ну а так, по вашему запросу нужно просто проверять ширину экрана:

```
$(document).width();
```

Comment: Не, так я знаю, как ширину получить. Было бы хорошо, если бы вы показали, как то, что обрабатывает клик работало до 675, а то что ховер - от 675

Comment: Самое простое, это наверно вот так:

    var $docWidth = $(document).width(); // авось где-нибудь пригодится
    if($docWidth > 500) {
        var $EventType = 'hover';
    }
    else {
        var $EventType = 'click';        
    }
 
 
    $('#nav').on($EventType, function(){
        console.log("наша функция");
    });

Answer (score 2):

Я сам делал так:

```
window.onload = function () {
   window._ScWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
   window._ScHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
};
window.onresize = function () {
    _ScWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    _ScHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;        
};
```

и у вас в `_ScWidth` будет хранится ширина а в `_ScHeight` - высота доступной странице области экрана всё время обновляющаяся...

Comment: А как мы можем на мобильниках изменять ширину браузера? Вы вопрос то читали?

Comment: >А как мы можем на мобильниках изменять ширину браузера? Вы вопрос то читали? 
@lampa - перевернув экран - изменим ширину/высоту, на Android 4.0.4 открыв несколько окон и изменяя размер окна браузера - изменим ширину/высоту. Подобный вопрос уже задавался и мой ответ был как раз тем, что нужно :)

Comment: @Rules хотя да, неподумал :) НО автору всё равно не то нужно.