# Обработка jquery  на планшетах

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Вот не могу не то, что бы найти, не могу   даже оформить запрос. Есть код JQuery но его надо запускать только на компьютерах, то есть что бы не запускался на планшетах и телефонах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяй уникальные для мобильных устройств свойства, например, событие touch. Вообще, лучше на сервере получить заголовки и в зависимости от них включать или не включать jquery.

**Обновление**

В переменной `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` собрана вся информация об устройстве и браузере посетителя.

Comment: А как получить заголовок того что страница открыта на телефоне или планшете ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь все хорошо написано :)[jQuery: разные функции для разной ширины экрана](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/188367/html-jquery-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)